# count letters of a file and create a histogram

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I'm looking for some help with an issue I'm facing.

I'm trying to read a text file, count the number of times each letter occurs in the file using a dictionary.

Uppercase letters are turned into lowercase letters and only a-z in English are counted. Then display a star histogram like below from the counts and print a count of the total amount of letters.

I had the first part working, count the number of times each letter occurs in the file, until I added in my histogram code.

I'm not getting an error but the Terminal just displays this when ran:

```
{'d': 1}
```

My current code is:

```
def LetterCount(file_path):
    file_path = file_path.lower().translate(file_path)
    file_path = file_path.translate(string.punctuation)
    file_path = file_path.strip(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)
    list1=list(file_path)
    lcDict= {}
    with open(file_path,'r') as f:
        for l in list1:
            if l.isalpha():
             if l in lcDict:
                  lcDict[l] +=1
             else:
                    lcDict[l]= 1
                    return lcDict
file_path = '/myfolder/text.txt'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(LetterCount(file_path))




def histogram(file_path):
    sumValues = LetterCount(file_path)
    padding = max(len(sumValues), len('Element'))
    padding1 = max(len(str(max(sumValues))), len('Value')) 
    print("\nCreating a histogram from values: ")
    print("%s %10s %10s" %("Element", "Value", "Histogram"))
    for i,n in enumerate(sumValues, start=1):
        ('{0} {1}     {2}'.format( 
              str(i).ljust(padding), 
              str(i).rjust(padding1), 
              '*'*n))
print(histogram(file_path)
```

What I'm trying to achieve from the histogram is this

```
a | *****
b | ***
c | ******
d | ****
e | *******
f | **
h | ***** 
...
z | *
```

I'd be really grateful for any help

Comment: Just one thing, if the letter appears 0 times, would you like to have the letter printed with no stars, or just skip the letter?

Comment: I would prefer it to be printed but with no stars

Comment: When you printed stuff at different places in your program did you see where it might be going wrong? If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `return lcDict` is **in** the for loop - it will return as soon as that `else` clause is executed.. I think you should dedent it to the same level as `with open(...`.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Much of your code deals with reading a file; much deals with display mechanics.  Much deals with letter counts.  Which portion has the problem?  Your code is not minimal, and it fails to run for several reasons.

Comment: @wwii that fixed the first part, thank you and now I'm getting this error: 
line 34, in histogram
    '*'*n)) 
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: @kgrusty - that sounds like a di9fferent question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because I don't have your file and cannot reproduce your specific example, I would answer the 2 questions apart.

First, in order to create an histogram as dictionary for your file (represented as list of strings) follow this part of code:

```
list_of_sentences = ["this is my first code in python", "it's rainy today", "thanks"]

m_dict = {}
for sentence in list_of_sentences:
    for letter in sentence:
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter in m_dict.keys():
                m_dict[letter]+= 1
            else:
                m_dict[letter] =1
print(m_dict)
```

output:

```
{'t': 6, 'h': 3, 'i': 6, 's': 5, 'm': 1, 'y': 4, 'f': 1, 'r': 2, 'c': 1, 'o': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'n': 4, 'p': 1, 'a': 3, 'k': 1}
```

The approach above will iterate over the letters in your file and count them, if you want to iterate over `a` to `z`, that for big files would be much efficient (moreover, it will print also letters that don't exist in your file), you better use this:

```
for code in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1):
    m_dict[chr(code)] = ''.join(list_of_sentences).count(chr(code))
```

output:

```
{'t': 6, 'h': 3, 'i': 6, 's': 5, 'm': 1, 'y': 4, 'f': 1, 'r': 2, 'c': 1, 'o': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'n': 4, 'p': 1, 'a': 3, 'k': 1, 'b': 0, 'g': 0, 'j': 0, 'l': 0, 'q': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'z': 0}
```

Now when we have the histogram in our hands (let's continue with the first one), let's face the second part of formatting it as you want to:

```
def print_as_histogram(m_dict):
    for letter in sorted(m_dict.keys()):
        print(f'{letter} | {"*"*m_dict[letter]}')

print_as_histogram(m_dict)
```

output:

```
a | ***
c | *
d | **
e | *
f | *
h | ***
i | ******
k | *
m | *
n | ****
o | ***
p | *
r | **
s | *****
t | ******
y | ****
```

Sorted the letters, because it looks better in my opinion

Comment: Wow that's much cleaner than what I had, thank you so much. Will this ignore non English words or would i have to use something like `s.ascii.lower`

Comment: `isalpha` will return `True` only for letters from `a` to `z`, pay attention to the edits, in order to count other letters but the ones who already in your file

Answer (score 0):

You can use some standard libraries to make your life a bit easier!

```
import collections
import re

# Open the file
with open("./file.txt", 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()

# Find all the alphabetic characters
letters = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]", txt)
# Count them
counts = collections.Counter(letters)

# Print the star histogram
for i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
    if i in counts:
        print(f"{i} | {'*' * counts[i]}")
    else: print(f"{i} | ")
```